# Javascript variable scope, store content to use it in callback

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, scope

I have a problem with the scope of a variable. I call a web service (asynchronous) and in the callback i want to use this variable. The problem is that the variable has changed meantime so i want to store it's content but it does'n work as i want.

```
var requiredFiles = ['config.json','resa.json', 'customers.json'];

retrieveAndStoreFiles(requiredFiles);


...

function retrieveAndStoreFiles(requiredFiles){

    for (var i= 0; i < requiredFiles.length; i++) {

         //I want to store the content of requiredFile in order to use it below
         retrieveFileOnServer(requiredFiles[i], function(response){

            if (response.items.length == 0 ) {

           //I have tried several things but requiredFile is always equal to 'customers.json'
           console.log(requiredFiles[i]);
           createNewFile(requiredFile[i], function(response){   

        });
    }
 }
```

As you can see, i have an array with 3 file's name. I try to retrieve them on the server, if they don't exist they are created. The var requiredFile is modified as it's asynchronous. I want to keep its own value inside the function "retrieveAndStoreFiles"

thx in advance

**EDIT** : updated code according to Romain's answer

**EDIT2**

```
for (var i = 0; i < requiredFiles.length; i++) {

        retrieveFile(requiredFiles[i], (function (index) { 

            console.log(index); //works
            var index = index; // index is still not accessible with that
            return function (response) { // function(response, index) is not possible, i must have only one parameter
            console.log(index); // index is not defined
            if (response.items.length == 0) {
                console.log(response);
                createNewFile(requiredFiles[index], function (response) {

                });
            }

        }

    })(i));
}
```

i tried to combine your solutions but it still doesn' work, can someone tell me what i am missing ? (sorry i am new to javascript)

**EDIT3**

```
function retrieveFile(fileName, callback) {

var request = gapi.client.request({
    'path': '/drive/v2/files',
    'method': 'GET',
    'params': {
        q : "title='"+fileName+"'"
    }           
}); 

request.execute(function(resp) {
    callback(resp);
});
}
```

when i try :

```
for(var i = 0; i < requiredFiles.length; i++) {
     window.setTimeout(
        ( function(arg1) {

            return function() {

               console.log(requiredFiles[arg1]);
            };
        } ) ( i ),
    1000
    );
}
```

it works, but this code doesnt work :

```
for(var i = 0; i < requiredFiles.length; i++) {
    retrieveFile(requiredFiles[i],
        ( function(arg1) {

            return function(reponse) {

               console.log(requiredFiles[arg1]); //arg1 is undefined
            };
        } ) ( i )
    );
}
```

Comment: it is working  http://jsbin.com/anemep/1/edit

Comment: Can you make a jsbin demo of what you have tried

Answer (score 4):

```
function retrieveAndStoreFiles(requiredFiles) {

    for (var i = 0; i < requiredFiles.length; i++) {

        (function (index) {
            //I want to store the content of requiredFile in order to use it below
            retrieveFileOnServer(requiredFiles[index], function (response) {

                if (response.items.length == 0) {

                    console.log(requiredFiles[index]);
                    createNewFile(requiredFile[index], function (response) {

                    });
                }

            });

        })(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
retrieveFileOnServer(requiredFile, (function(requiredFile) {return function(response){
    if (response.items.length == 0 ) {

        //I have tried several things but requiredFile is always equal to 'customers.json'
        console.log(requiredFile);
        createNewFile(requiredFile, function(response){ 
            //...
        });
    }
}})(requiredFile));
```

The problem is that `requiredFile` only exists once, in the scope of `retrieveAndStoreFiles`. And so will always take on the last value that was seen. This, providing I have the number of open and close brackets and stuff correct, should create a new entry in the scope chain for the function `function(response)` which has the variable `requiredFile` in it set to the right value.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures for more information on the dark magics.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call the retrieveAndStoreFiles function in a loop.

You should have the function calling itself, incrementing "i".

This way you're sure the request has been done before running the function on the next element.

Comment: yes i have already tried that, it was my first try, but i have the same problem doing like this